# VS2019 error with SQL Change Automation: "Keyword not supported: 'multiple active result sets'"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, readyroll

I don't know where this error comes from at all. I have set up SQL Change Automation in VS2019 and began to get these errors for each .sqlproj solution I have. The errors are marked in the .sqlproj file, but no line is given for any of them.

I also don't can't find those words in the .sqlproj files, nor "MultipleActiveResultSets". I don't have them in the .sqlproj.users files neither.

Does anyone know if this is a known error with SQL Change Automation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue of SQL Change Automation has been reported in [their forum discussion 87146](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/87146/invalid-connection-string-keyword-not-supported-multiple-active-result-sets-when-changing-conn)

There you can find the workaround:

> unload the project, then modify the connection string from "`Multiple Active Result Sets`" to "`MultipleActiveResultSets`" (remove the spaces).

I found the connection string in the [project]`.sqlproj.user` file.

In some project I also had to remove the spaces from "`Trust Server Certificate`".

For instance, it used to say:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Dbname;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False</TargetConnectionString>
```

and I manually changed into:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Dbname;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;</TargetConnectionString>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had already read that post and it did help. I'll mark your answer as the one that solved it since it has the official RedGate team's answer to it.

Comment: This is the right answer for me too. Instead of changing the individual properties, I copied the string from the `SQL Change Automation >> Configure database connection >> Advanced Properties`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a new bug in SQL Change Automation.

I could fix it, with pressing the "Restore Default" button for the "Target Connection String" in the project properties in the debug register.

[Target Connection String - Restore Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMD4L.jpg)