# Multiple Active Result Sets vs MultipleActiveResultSets

Tags: deployment, connection-string, visual-studio-2022

Using VS 2022 for deploying an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC app it get an issue.
The build-in deployment dialog generates a connection string like this:
...;Multiple Active Result Sets=true;...
But on the Server running IIS I get an error that "Multiple Active Result Sets" is not recognized.
Changing the connection string to ;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; fixes the issue.

That is also true for trusting server certificates options etc.
Is there a way to update the .NET CLR used by IIS to be capable of handling ...;Multiple Active Result Sets=true;...?

Deploy a ISS hosted web site using the VS 2022 deployment wizard and transforming the connection string using ...;Multiple Active Result Sets=true;...

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717452/vs2019-error-with-sql-change-automation-keyword-not-supported-multiple-activ